# Is there a way to use the nested route ID as a prop argument in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, nested, react-router

So basically I have an array of gallery items which contains class "GalleryItem" objects (contains gallery name and list of images and their names).

I also have a component called "Gallery" which takes GalleryItem class object as a prop and renders it.

What I want to do is possibility to navigate with .../galleries/:galleryName to rendering the specific gallery inside single page.

Galleries render fine, but I need this to work together with nested routes!

```
<Switch>
<Route path="/galleries/:name" render={(props) => <Gallery {...props} galleryItem={this.state.galleryItems[:name]} />} />
<Switch>
```

Obviously this doesn't work so I'm asking how it's done and what to know if I'm doing that absolutely wrong.

Comment: You can get `match` form props in Gallery component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Route` component [passes three props to the consuming component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props):

- match
- location
- history

You want to [use the `match` prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) to get your gallery name:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/galleries/:name"
    render={props => (
      <Gallery
        {...props}
        galleryItem={this.state.galleryItems[props.match.params.name]}
      />
    )}
  />
<Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

The prop match is going to contain information about how the Route was matched. You can do something like this:

```
<Route
    path="/galleries/:name"
    exact
    render={props => 
      <Gallery {...props} galleryItem={galleryItems(props.match.path.split(':')[1])} />
    }

/>
```